# Alamofire 2 requests succeeds even when given a bad http statuscode in the response

Tags: alamofire

Now that I've upgraded to Alamofire 2, I've noticed that the callback considers responses to be a success even if it returns a non 200 or 4xx http response.

Is that the intended behavior?  What's the recommended way of checking for the bad responses - just manually checking the response.statusCode?

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://somesite.org/private")
         .responseJSON { _, _, result in
             print(result.isSuccess) // is true even if it's a 403 or 404 response
         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is default behavior. I think you have to validate the response. Everything outside the provided status codes will be handled as failure.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://somesite.org/private")
     .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
     .responseJSON { _, _, result in
         print(result.isSuccess) // is true even if it's a 403 or 404 response
     }
```